# Trouble working with EF contexts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm stumbling my way through working with entity framework and the database context as it's all very new to me.

I have a method called GetEnrolleeName that is supposed to accept as an argument, the id of a file, and return a string which is the name of the enrollee associated with that file.  There is some sort of conflict between the methods running on the same context and I don't know how to resolve it.  Here is the code from my controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> TestIndex()
{
    var reports = (from r in _context.DailyObservationReport
                      select new DailyObservationReport()
                      {
                          Id = r.Id,
                          EnrolleeName = Report.GetEnrolleeName(r.FileId, _context), //here is the call I am having trouble with
                          AuthorId = Report.GetAuthorName(r.Id, _context),
                          DayOfTraining = r.DayOfTraining,
                          DateOfTraining = r.DateOfTraining
                      }).ToList();

    var vm = new IndexViewModel()
    {
        Reports = reports
    };

    return View(vm);
}
```

here is the GetEnrolleName method:

```
public class Report
{
    public static string GetEnrolleeName(int FileId, ApplicationDbContext _context)
    {
        var x =
            (from f in _context.File
            where f.ID == FileId
            join u in _context.Users
            on f.EnrolleeId equals u.Id
            into FileEnrollee
            from e in FileEnrollee
            select new
            {
                LastName = e.LastName,
                FirstName = e.FirstName,
                MiddleName = e.MiddleName
            }).SingleOrDefault();

        string n = x.LastName + ", " + x.FirstName + " " + x.MiddleName;

        return n;
     }
}
```

This produces an exception:

> **System.InvalidOperationException:** 'A second operation started on this
>   context before a previous operation completed.  Any instance members
>   are not guaranteed to be thread safe'

I'm sure there is an issue with sending the context as an argument from one class to another but it's the easiest thing I could think of to work.  I need some help resolving the error above and getting this to work properly.

Comment: You're first select statement (db call) is then calling another select statement (db call) per row returned.  EF does not support this.  You'll have to get your first set of rows, then for each row you could call your second function.

Comment: Have you tried replacing .ToList() for .ToListAsync()? EF can handle async now.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I kinda wanted to do it all in one go, but honestly, your way is probably the best options.

Comment: Well the problem is that you are introducing C# code in a method so it can't be done in one go.  If it was re-written it could be done in one call.

Comment: @ErikPhilips How so?  The only thing I can think of is a pretty elaborate join

Comment: @StateofDK I see you are using `SingleOrDefault`, is that because you want it to error out if there are more than a single result or are you trying to reduce the result to a single object (not an collection)?

Comment: @ErikPhilips trying to reduce the result to a single object.  I only plan on using this method in retrieving names for single objects or else in looping through a collection and retrieving each name individually if needed.

Comment: Any reason you are using manual joins instead of EF Relationships?

Comment: The only reason is really that I wanted to use this project to learn EF code-first.  I've never used it before so this seemed like a good opportunity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163835/discussion-between-erik-philips-and-stateofdk).

Comment: If you're doing it to learn ef, then I highly suggest you start reading on EF Realtionships.  All of these joins can be completely removed and replace with a single `include()` line of code.  Definitely learn that (EF Relationships) first, because going down the road you are is making it more difficult.

Comment: I have to agree with @ErikPhilips